# Split a line from a file to replace elements in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Open file to read
2. split lines
3. Identify lines of interest
4. replace Name `Prefix_2` with `Prefix_999`
5. delete all lines with `Prefix_1`
6. save lines to original file

I can do up to point 3 but when it comes to replacing the names I cant seem to split the line of interest into elements so that I can replace `Prefix_2` with `Prefix_999`

It always replaces with entire line of interest as shown below e.g.

`Prefix_2.Var1 = 5124` will replace to `Prefix_999` rather than `Prefix_999.Var1 = 5124`

Example data in file `Data.txt`

```
Prefix_1.Var1 = 200
Prefix_1.Var2 = 0.3
Prefix_1.Var3 = 0.5
Prefix_1.Var4 = 0.25
Prefix_1.Var5 = 3
Prefix_1.Var6 = 36
Prefix_1.Var7 = 5612
Prefix_1.Var8 = 631
Prefix_1.Var9 = 102
Prefix_1.Var10 = 14
Prefix_1.Var11 = 3
Prefix_1.Var12 = 2
Prefix_2.Var1 = 5124
Prefix_2.Var2 = 876
Prefix_2.Var3 = 10.1
Prefix_2.Var4 = 11
```

My code:

```
set input [open "Data.txt" r]

set number 0
set var2 ""
while { [gets $input line] >= 0 } {
    incr number
    set sline [split $line "\n"]
    set var1 [regexp {Prefix_2.Var1} $sline match]
    if {$var1 == 1} {
        set rVar1 [split $sline \s]
        # check the length to index correctly for replacing
        set rVar2 [llength $rVar1]
        set rVar2 [lreplace $rVar2 0 0 Prefix_999.Var1]
    }
}

close $input
```

Comment: You are replacing against variable `rVar2` which has the length of the actual intended data. Not the actual list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not writing a text filter, you might be better off working on a higher level.

```
proc processLine {bufName line} {
    upvar 1 $bufName buf
    switch -regexp $line {
        {^Prefix_1\.} {}
        {^Prefix_2\.} {
            lappend buf [regsub 2 $line 999]
        }
        default {
            lappend buf $line
        }
    }
}

package require fileutil

set buf {}
fileutil::foreachLine line data.txt {
    processLine buf $line
}
fileutil::writeFile data.txt [join $buf \n]
```

The lower-level `open`-`gets`-`close` combo is part of the language core; the `fileutil` package that can be used to abstract away most usages of this combo is a part of `Tcllib`, the companion library for Tcl.

I'm working with your specification here, since your code is a little hard to follow.

1. Open file to read
2. split lines
3. Identify lines of interest
4. replace Name Prefix_2 with Prefix_999
5. delete all lines with Prefix_1
6. save lines to original file

**Identify lines of interest**

The `processLine` command will be receiving each line in the parameter `line`. The `switch -regexp $line {...}` command lets me classify the lines, by prefix (or by whatever, the criteria can be anything that can be expressed by a regular expression). There are three classes of lines: those that start with "Prefix_1", those that start with "Prefix_2", and all other lines. I make it a default action to save lines in a persistent buffer (which is called `buf` inside the command and `$bufName` outside it: in my code both names are the same).

**replace Name Prefix_2 with Prefix_999**

For lines that start with "Prefix_2", I skip the default action and instead save a modified line where the first occurrence of 2 is replaced by 999.

**delete all lines with Prefix_1**

This requirement is fulfilled simply by skipping the default action for these lines.

**Open file to read** and **split lines**

This is done automatically by `fileutil::foreachLine`.

**save lines to original file**

I simply join the lines in the buffer with newline characters and invoke `fileutil::writeFile` to update the file.

---

**ETA** a version without `upvar`

The line processing command doesn't have to access the line buffer directly; instead it can simply return lines (skipped lines being empty strings). In this case assembling the line buffer needs to be performed in the script argument to `foreachLine`:

```
proc processLine line {
    switch -regexp $line {
        {^Prefix_1\.} {}
        {^Prefix_2\.} {
            regsub 2 $line 999
        }
        default {
            return $line
        }
    }
}

package require fileutil

set buf {}
fileutil::foreachLine line data.txt {
    set line [processLine $line]
    if {$line ne {}} {
        lappend buf $line
    }
}
fileutil::writeFile data.txt [join $buf \n]
```

(I'd rate this version as inferior.)

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: I like using `foreachLine` and `writeFile`; they take the I/O out of the problem. You should mention that the `fileutil` package is part of Tcllib, in case that makes it easier for someone to find it.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works well. However I'm still trying to understand buf and bufName. however I have encountered another problem with deleting lines...there are some variables with same prefix which are tables rather than constants. There as left behind, I raise this in another post if required.

Comment: @Anju: I've added a version where you don't need `upvar`, but the variable linking facility is very useful, one of those features where Tcl shines over most other languages, so I recommend that you take the time to learn how it works. Regarding your other problem, another post is probably the best way to raise that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regsub` for your purpose.

```
% set line {Prefix_2.Var1 = 5124}           
Prefix_2.Var1 = 5124 
% regsub {Prefix_2} $line {Prefix_999} 
Prefix_999.Var1 = 5124
%
```