# Deleting lines between two instances of interest within a file in tcl

Tags: tcl

Earlier I had asked some help to delete and replace contents of a file. With Peter's help and example that problem was solved ([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234680/split-a-line-from-a-file-to-replace-elements-in-tcl)). However it created another one, this issue relates to deleting lines.

So here is the question, I can delete lines for every instance of ***Prefix_1*** that appears in the file.

However there are lines between two instances that are skipped (because the line does not start with Prefix_1), hence is left in the file.

I do know that Line starts with Prefix_1 followed by a dot then variable name and ends with either space and equal sign or colon.

Every line that ends with colon has a table associated with it.

Would I identify the two classes of lines one ending with space and equal sign and the other with colon. Then, whenever colon is detected delete all line until next instance of Prefix_1 is detected?

```
Prefix_1.Var1 = -2
Prefix_1.Var2 = 1
Prefix_1.Var3:
    1.1 1.3 1.8 15 1.9 0.1 16 71 31 16 12 1 881 199 19 100 1000 1005 1005 1005
Prefix_1.Var4 = 1
Prefix_1.Var5:
    40 50 75 100 150
Prefix_1.Var6:
    4
    7
    15
    25
    35
    45
Prefix_1.Var7:
    #TABLE 30 2 5 6
    70       70       70       70       70       100      100
    81       80       80       100      100      81       80
    80       100      100      81       80       80       100
    100      82       81       81       100      100      87
    87       87
Prefix_1.Var8 = 1
Prefix_1.Var9 = 65
Prefix_1.Var10:
    255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
Prefix_1.Var11:
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 6 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Prefix_1.Var12 = 30
```

After I delete all lines with Prefix_1, I'm still left with these lines which fall in between two instances of Prefix_1.

I want to delete these too.

```
1.1 1.3 1.8 15 1.9 0.1 16 71 31 16 12 1 881 199 19 100 1000 1005 1005 1005
40 50 75 100 150
4
7
15
25
35
45
#TABLE 30 2 5 6
70       70       70       70       70       100      100
81       80       80       100      100      81       80
80       100      100      81       80       80       100
100      82       81       81       100      100      87
87       87
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 6 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: General strategy: Split file up into chunks where each chunk is something that will be retained or removed. Then for each chunk decide whether to keep it. The chunking strategy just happens to be not “split into single lines”…

Comment: so- you apart from regsub 2 to 999 , you want delete all prefix1 data , Am I right ?

Comment: I've added example of before and after file processing

Comment: I don't understand your question. As I read it, every line in your sample input should be deleted.

Comment: unfortunately it does not delete every line, I'll have another try and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*This answer extends my [earlier answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234680/split-a-line-from-a-file-to-replace-elements-in-tcl/36238327#36238327).*)

Simple fix: replace

```
    default {
        lappend buf $line
    }
```

with

```
    {^Prefix} {
        lappend buf $line
    }
    default {}
```

if you're using the `upvar` variant, or

```
    default {
        return $line
    }
```

with

```
    {^Prefix_} {
        return $line
    }
    default {}
```

otherwise.

This means that the default action is to skip a line, and that lines will be kept only if they have a numbered prefix other than "Prefix_1".

This solution doesn't adhere to the data syntax in the file, which is unsatisfactory, but if it works it should be good enough.

**Counting occurrences of Prefix_1**

You can record line numbers for the first and last line that starts with "Prefix_1", but to do that you need even more data that is persistent outside the processing command. It might be a good time to switch to object-oriented programming.

```
oo::class create LineProcessor {
    variable first last count buffer
    constructor args {
        set first 0
        set last 0
        set count 0
        set buffer {}
    }
    method process line {
        incr count
        switch -regexp $line {
            {^Prefix_1\.} {
                if {$first == 0} {
                    set first $count
                }
                set last $count
                return {}
            }
            {^Prefix_2\.} {
                lappend buffer [regsub 2 $line 999]
            }
            {^Prefix_} {
                lappend buffer $line
            }
            default {}
        }
    }
    method dump {} {
        join $buffer \n
    }
    method report {} {
        puts "First/last line with Prefix_1: $first/$last"
    }
}

LineProcessor create lp

fileutil::foreachLine line data.txt {
    lp process $line
}
fileutil::writeFile data.txt [lp dump]
lp report
# => First/last line with Prefix_1: 1/40
```

This code is more or less the same as before, only with some logic to record line numbers in the clause for "Prefix_1", and with supporting variables encapsulated in an object instead of being global data.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works to some extent. I think I might be able to expand this a bit more. Btw is it possible to find out line number the first time and last time "Prefix_1" occurs in a file? I can count number of times the pattern occurs and total number of lines in the file, but cannot robustly get the first and last time Perfix_1 occurs.